# storing date as number and convert number back in to date equivalent

Tags: c#, .net

is there easy way to store dates as number and convert number to date equivalent in .NET 3.5 such as julian date format?.

Comment: I want to store it in variable and pass to query string parameter to another asp.net page and convert back again the value to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time Tick gives a big number with lot of zeros so its not suitable for asp.net query string parameter values but might work for some other situations.So julian date conversions are the most easy and nice way to use in asp.net query string date value passing between pages

Answer (score 6):

You can use [DateTime.Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) to convert a DateTime to a number (more specifically - a long). Use the [constructor that takes ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx) to convert back.

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime.ToOADate() → double → DateTime.FromOADate()
DateTime.ToFileTime() → long → DateTime.FromFileTime()
DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc() → long → DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc()
```

All of these methods will convert a DateTime to a numeric.

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine for you

```
      DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
      long dateAsLong = date.ToFileTime();
      DateTime orgDate = DateTime.FromFileTime(dateAsLong);
```